# Equivalent characterisation of an independent family $\mathcal{F}$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$, given that $\mathcal{F}$ is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition:
A family $\mathcal{F}$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$ is independent if for any $I$, $J\in fin(\mathcal{F})$ (finite subsets of $\mathcal{F}$) with $I \cap J = \emptyset$ we have
$$\bigcap I \setminus \bigcup J \, \, \, \,\text{is infinite.}
$$
Problem:
Assume $\mathcal{F}$ is infinite. Show that then  $\mathcal{F}$ is independent if and only if for any $I$, $J\in fin(\mathcal{F})$ (finite subsets of $\mathcal{F}$) with $I \cap J = \emptyset$ we have
$$\bigcap I \setminus \bigcup J \neq \emptyset .
$$

The only if part is clear to me but I am having trouble with the other direction. It seems like it should be relatively simple but I don't really know how to start. A hint would be preferred over a full answer, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\bigcap I\setminus\bigcup J=A$ for some finite $A\subseteq \omega$, and let $X\in\mathcal F\setminus(I\cup J)$.

Show that $\bigcap (I\cup \{X\})\setminus\bigcup J=B\ne A$.

What does this tells us about $|B|$? Try to conclude from that there exists $I',J\in fin(\mathcal F)$ such that $\bigcap I'\setminus\bigcup J=\emptyset$

Comment: Could you please explain how you can be sure that $X$ is not a superset of $\bigcap I$. E.g $I$ consists of multiples of 9 and multiples of 27. Let $X$ be the multiples of 3. Then X satisfies your first condition but $A=B$. If instead you require $X \in \mathcal{F} \setminus ( \bigcup I \cup \bigcup J) $. Then you get right away that $B = \emptyset$. I think?

Comment: Assume $X$ is a superset of $\bigcap I$, then what is the value of $\bigcap I\setminus\bigcup (J\cup\{X\})$? Is this value possible?

Comment: @Holo I am sorry but I don't understand how that is relevant when we were talking about $\bigcap (I \cup {X}) \setminus \bigcup J$? And isn't my example a counterexample to your clain that $A \neq B$? I am so confused.

Comment: @Student if $\bigcap (I\cup \{X\})\setminus\bigcup J=A$, it means that $X$ is a super set of $\bigcap I$, in particular $\bigcap I\setminus\bigcup (J\cup\{X\})=∅$, but this is directly contradict our assumption

Comment: @Holo aren't we proving the contrapositive and actually trying to get finite disjoint $I'$, $J'$ such that $\bigcap I' \setminus \bigcup J' = \emptyset$? So that actually wouldn't contradict any assumption. And is my technique of choosing $X \in \mathcal{F} \setminus ( \bigcup I \cup \bigcup J)$ and getting $\bigcap (I \cup {X}) \setminus \bigcup J = \emptyset$ incorrect?

Comment: @Student we are assuming that every disjoint $I,J$ have $\bigcap I\setminus \bigcup J$ is non empty and we want to prove that $\bigcap I\setminus \bigcup J$ is infinite. I started by assuming $\bigcap I\setminus \bigcup J$ is non-empty but finite, if we find some $I',J'$ such that $\bigcap I'\setminus \bigcup J'$ it means we have a contradiction and there are no $I,J$ such that $\bigcap I\setminus \bigcup J$ is non-empty finite, so either it is sometimes empty, or it is always infinite, but it is given that it is never empty, so it is always infinite

Comment: $\bigcup I \cup \bigcup J$ is a subset of $\omega$, and $\cal F$ is a *set of infinite subsets* of $\omega$, so ${\cal F}\setminus (\bigcup I \cup \bigcup J)=\cal F$